# Infinite Gradle Build Running Java 8

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, java-8, android-7.0-nougat

I try to migrate from Java 7 to Java 8, so I have install the new sdk for Android N and all tools. I follow the [developper guide to use Java 8 in android studio](https://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html#supported-features), but when i try to compile apk, I have an infinite Gradle Build Running.. I already try to restart Android Studio, but after 1 hour, the Gradle Build Running it's not finished. In the Windows task manager I see the process java.exe take a lot of memory and CPU was at 90%.

Someone already encountered this problem ?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

I have the following versions :

```
Java version : 1.8.0_92
Gradle version : 2.1.2
Android Studio version : 2.1.2

compileSdkVersion : 24
buildToolsVersion : 24

targetSdkVersion : 24
```

**Edit2:**

I tried with Android Studio 2.2 and 5 minutes after starting the build, I have this error :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileProductionDebugJavaWithJack'. 
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Comment: what is max java heap size?

Comment: The max heap size it's 1065353216 (1GB)

Comment: I have the same problem with infinite builds.

Comment: What you actually use for building(gradle version)? Problem can be in your gradle wraper. Try to use gradle deamon for building

Comment: I edit my post to add versions. I already use the deamon, but with or without it doesn't works.

Comment: @Johann67 I'm encountering the exact same problem. Did you solve it by now?

Answer (score 2):

add these lines to your gradle.properties file

```
org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home //edit this according to your java home path

org.gradle.daemon=true

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

org.gradle.parallel=true

org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

Comment: Added the last 4 lines and it worked like a charm. Can you please explain how this works?

Answer (score 1):

When you run Android Studio for the first time, it will download some initial plugins and the delay depends on the internet connection speed and some other things. But you may want to run the IDE in offline mode. To do so, go to 
File -> Settings 
and then 'Build, Execution, Deployment' -> 'Build Tools' -> 'Gradle'
and enable 'Offline work' checkbox.

Sorry, I couldn't comment this because of low reputation :D

Answer (score 0):

Try to run you project via gradle. For this go to your project root and run `gradle installDebug` (install gradle if needed). If almost done well change Android Studio config for installed gradle usage. If build failed try to run same command with --debug or --info option. Sometimes AS detects runtime bugs but stacks without any info(infinite build loop). Check in your project structure valid JDK location (must be 1.8 or similar to this). Also you can try clean your AS cache: for this go to File->Invalidate Caches/Restart, before this go to "Build" -> Clean Project. 
And one more recommendation(you can also try it) switch your AS update channel to Canary, and update it to 2.2 version. I'm not tested n-sdk as well on my 2.1.2 studio, but on 2.2 it work more stable. 
By the way, you also can get problem with JDK. I use JDK from Oracle, it more stable for me(must work with OpenJDK also, but i have a lot of problem early).

Comment: Not correct, this is the first time he builds gradle in AS ever since he upgraded Java. It needs to download a bunch of files, therefor it will take long.

Comment: @AbAppletic, in my case, it's descriptions which helps me in 90% of AS problems. You can't be sure, while don't see dependencies which topic starter add to his project.

Comment: And, so, key words: "I try to migrate from Java 7 to Java 8". Seems to me it's not first start.

Comment: When you re-install java, Android Studio needs to re-download Gradle files. I've done it before.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have try with android studio 2.2 and I have new error (after 5 minutes) ! `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileProductionDebugJavaWithJack'. > java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`

Comment: Add your build.gradle content please

Answer (score 0):

The first time you build Gradle in AS, it will take an hour sometimes.

This is because it is downloading a bunch of files. You just have to wait. It has to download more gradle files and at the end it will just finish.

It should take from 1-2 hours depending on your connection. Could take less or more. Just wait! :)

---

Note that you can't do anything about it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Gradle run for an hour and a half.. but nothing for the moment :/. I have a good connection, with fiber. But i see java.exe running 90% of CPU and use a lot of memory. I think the problem it's not gradle but maybe java.

Comment: @Johann67 Wait until it is 2 hours, then restart AS and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem...
If you are under ubuntu you can fix that by installing 32 libs.
Fix android bug compilation on ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0

sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
```